# Implicitly convert integers to class 'BigInt'

Tags: c++, casting, int

I've made this class BigInt, and it it has derived transformation constructors such as

```
BigInt::BigInt(int l):InfInt(l){}
```

Yet when I do something like this:

```
for(i=0;BigInt::pow(2,i+1)<exponent;i++);
```

The compiler yells at me for:

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘BigInt’ and ‘int’)
```

I know a simple way to fix this is simply to add (BigInt) in front of everything, like this:

```
for(i=0;BigInt::pow(2,i+(BigInt)1)<exponent;i++);
```

But this code looks ugly, somewhat hard to read, and is a pain to type. Is there a way to tell the compiler to do this right away (as the title already says) ? It's not too dramatic if there isn't though. 
Oh, and excuse me if this has been already asked, but I have tried to search for a solution on my own on google and here and have found nothing that could help me out. (I was mostly able to find stuff about `operator int()` and the like, which I already knew about).

Comment: why don't you provide an overload of `operator+` that takes an `int` as the argument?

Comment: Or a constructor that takes an `int`.

Comment: @Nim Because I'd have to do that for every type, and I'm wondering if there's a smarter way of doing it.

Comment: No you don't, you can add `int` to `BigInt`, I would have thought that would be it... what else do you want to add to it? If so, you can add selective support..

Comment: @BoBTFish I have one, I've mentionned it in the first lines of my post. Or were you talking about a different type of constructor ?

Comment: @Nim Well, I'd wanna add most integer types such as long and long long, and maybe even double (though I probably won't need those overloads anyway)

Comment: @Rudy132 No, I'm just an idiot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have an `operator int()`, don't you? That, plus the constructor that takes an `int`, produces the ambiguity. The compiler can call `BigInt::operator+()` by converting the `int` argument to a `BigInt`, or it can call the built-in `+` by converting the `BigInt` object to an `int`. Mark the `operator int()` `explicit` to get rid of this ambiguity. That will lead to failed conversions in a few situations, which can be resolved by adding a cast. That's the best you can do; there are no conversion precedence rules that can make the compiler see `BigInt` as the largest integral type.

Comment: Sometimes those failed conversions will actually be useful, even. For example you accidentally pass a `BigInt` to some function that has several overloads for different types, assuming it has a `BigInt` overload when actually it doesn't (perhaps it's supposed to but you haven't written it yet). If it implicitly converts to `int` then the compiler will silently use that. It's like what you get for `long long` by enabling `-Werror -Wconversion`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is. Does comparing against this help:

```
#include <iostream> 

struct MyInt
{
    MyInt(int i) : m_i(i) {}
    MyInt operator+(const MyInt& myint) const
    {
        return MyInt(m_i+myint.m_i);
    }     
    int m_i;
};     

int main()
{
    MyInt a(10);
    MyInt b(5);
    MyInt c1 = a + b;
    MyInt c2 = a + 5;

    std::cout << c1.m_i << std::endl;
    std::cout << c2.m_i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```